# Issue is This function shows me same product_id output on related products

Tags: php, opencart2.x

The issue is Output on related products it shows on every related product box same total counted number in **OpenCart**. So, it see just main `product_id`. So, must indicate related `product_id` somehow. I tried many many ways but it don`t work for me. Can someone help me to fix this?

There is function on modules:

```
public function getUnitsSold($product_id) {
                    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(op.quantity) AS total FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_product` op LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o ON (op.order_id = o.order_id) WHERE o.order_status_id = '5' AND op.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'"); 
                if ($query->row) {
                    return $query->row['total'];
                } else {
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }
```

And this is simply template output.

```
         <?php if ($tproducts) { ?>
           <?php foreach ($tproducts as $product) { ?>
        <?php if ($product['units_sold']) { ?>
        <?php echo $text_units_sold; ?> <?php echo $product['units_sold']; ?> 
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

In controller where is related product array is a possibility to indicate maybe this function query and then make right output.
something like that `units_sold`?

```
$data['tproducts'][] = array(

                'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],

                'units_sold'  => $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(op.quantity) AS total FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_product` op LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o ON (op.order_id = o.order_id) WHERE o.order_status_id = '5' AND op.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'"),

            );
```

or maybe

```
$data['tproducts'][] = array(

                'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],

                'units_sold'  => $this->model_catalog_product->getUnitsSold($this->request->get['product_id']),

            );
```

Comment: `<?php echo "Don't"; ?>` these `<?php echo "hurt"; ?>` your `<?php echo "eyes"; ?>` ?

Comment: @Chris: Opencart hurts, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to store the amount of sold items on the item itself.
Increment the number as if it is a reverse stock.
So, I'd just ALTER TABLE `oc_product` ADD `amount_sold` INT(8) NULL DEFAULT NULL;

Then, just display that simple column value. The storage of the orders must be modified and becomes a little bit slower (in the order of .001 - .0001s).

This way the store will keep performing well in the future, even when your order item table has become huge.

Let the storage handler be the working horse. Take a look at ModelCheckoutOrder::addOrderHistory(), when they subtract the quantity, you must add your quantity :)

`"UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET /*.... opencart default shit */, amount_sold = (amount_sold + " . (int)$order_product['quantity'] . ")`

Comment: Soo it should look like that ? $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET quantity = (quantity - amount_sold = (amount_sold + " . (int)$order_product['quantity'] . ") WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$order_product['product_id'] . "' AND subtract = '1'");

Comment: If the storage works ok now, you just need to use the column 'amount_sold'.
Step 1: Modifiy ControllerProductProduct::index() to include 'amount_sold' in $data. (It will be available from  $this->model_catalog-_product->getProduct() near line 159, because it selects * from the product table already). So just add in if($product_info){$data['amount_sold'] = $product_info['amount_sold']
Step 2: Modify template to point to 'amount_sold'.

Done :)